# Python netCDF4 - variable indexing

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

What would be the best way to index a netCDF4 .nc file to get a batch of variable values at once?

The dimensions I have are time, latitude and longitude. My code looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4

df = netCDF4.Dataset(r"some_file.nc", mode="r")
temperature_2m = df_weather.variables['t2m']
```

I have also build a numpy array (n by 3) with the indices (triplets of time, lat, lon) of all the temperatures I want. However, I now note I cannot do something like:

```
arr_idxs = np.zeros(shape=(1000,3))
temperature_2m[arr_idxs]
```

I was hoping something like this would give me a 1d array back with the temperatures for (in this example case) the first dimension of time, lat and lon repeated 1000 times, but I can't make it work.

What would be the best way to approach this? It is a very large file (millions of datapoints) so I'm needing a vectorized approach rather then a for loop.

Comment: Check out `xarray`, specifically the [documentation on reading `netcdf`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#netcdf)

Comment: This can be easily done using xarray. Check the indexing and selecting portion of the documentation.